# Most efficient way to move an inline class, interface, or enum to it's own file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

Sometimes when I'm developing I may prefer to quickly inline classes, interfaces and/or enums when I'm building a fresh design or from within a test fixture. However, I find it inconvenient to interrupt my thought process to create new code files, copy and paste the class/interface/enum written inline to the new file, and all the time it takes to navigate between them.

I'm looking for an extension, macro, or hidden shortcut combo that will automatically create a file for the highlighted or selected inline class/interface/enum, and, if possible, copy the using list so that it can be built (but remove & sort will clean it up later).

I'm open to extensions, macros, or hidden shortcut keys. Suggestions?

**Edit #1:** ReSharper looks awesome, yes, and it appears to have exactly what I need, but I would like to find a free solution, if it exists, that didn't push me back $200.

**Edit #2:** After your helpful input, I'm pushing for my dev team to all run the ReSharper trial, and re-evaluate in a few weeks if the value-add is worth it. We want keep our extension use consistent, so I'm hoping we all find it equally worthwhile.

**Example**: I want to turn this (IExample.cs):

```
using System.Linq;

public interface IExample
{
}

public class Example : IExample
{
}

public enum ExampleType
{
}
```

...into these:

IExample.cs:

```
using System.Linq;

public interface IExample
{
}
```

Example.cs

```
using System.Linq;

public class Example : IExample
{
}
```

ExampleType.cs

```
using System.Linq;

public enum ExampleType
{
}
```

Comment: Do you have ReSharper or something similar?

Comment: +1 for ReSharper's [Move Types To Matching Files](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Types_into_Matching_Files) function.

Comment: Nay. The price always seemed a little steep... but maybe this will help take me over the edge. :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a potential job for a macro? You'd have to put up with VBA though...

Comment: oh, how I miss eclipse sometimes when programming in Visual Studio (Eclipse has this for free, sure, the older versions were crappier, and sometimes it doesn't work well with some plugins, but if you get it stable enough, it's awesome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper offers the feature [Move to another file to match type name](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Types_into_Matching_Files), the ALT+Enter shortcut makes your work faster.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I want. However, it would be awesome if there was an alternative extension for this particular feature that didn't cost so much.

Answer (score 3):

The built in refactoring tools do not have a simple way to extract a class to its own file, so the simplest thing to do if you do not have a refactoring tool like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or [Refactor! Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/products/visual_studio_add-in/Coding_Assistance/refactor_pro.xml) that do have it is to:

1. Copy the class to memory.
2. Add a new file with the class name.
3. Paste the class to the new file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I wasn't missing something obvious. :)

Comment: @MattBeckman - You _could_ write a macro to do some (or possibly all) of the work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx

Comment: I had thought of using a macro, but it'll take some work. I haven't written one before, and it feels like a bit of blackhole given that stuff like Resharper are already out there... man, why am I so cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress Refactor!pro can be your solution....in example you posted, refactor! Pro shows a quick action menu at the bottom of the class name that you want to move.
In this Actionmenu there s the "Move to file" option that' s all you need....

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Apparently, this method does move the type to its own file but still keeps the relationship with the previous class, so it won't actually change anything other than generate a seperate file. The type will still be nested in the same way.

This is a pretty old question and I just encountered the same issue.
In Visual Studio 2019 (and probably in 2017 as well, though I did not check),
you can select the entire class -> right click -> Quick Actions and Refactoring -> Move Type to its own file.
It correct all references to said type, too.
Very handy!